# How to enable traditional window placement/ geometry positioning

Tags: 14.04, unity, window-manager, window-decoration

I have some remote X programs that all worked nice with 12.04.  But in 14.04 there is now the following change.

One program (emacs) calls another (gs) with a certain geometry specification.  The idea is to make this other window visible atop of emacs.

The geometry-information is no longer taken directly (as in 12.04). Instead, the shading border around the window is now added to the placement. Is there a way to tell Unity that a specifc app should be handled in the "olde" fashion?

When opening that (gs) window, it is placed below the current window. So it remains invisible. Ideally, I would like it to be placed on top - that is above emacs, and even to stay on top. Or almost. In 12.04 it worked reasonably enough. Is there a way to tell Unity that this window should stay on top? Maybe this has something to do with a maybe changed focus policy.

So far, with `wmctrl -r ghostscript -b add,above`, I can make a currently existing window "on top". However, I would like to apply this also for future windows. Similar to the "Staysontop" property of traditional window managers.

So far, I have `apt-get install compiz-plugins` to get Window Rules.  And there I have added `title=ghostscript` as matches under Above. (I got the title from the + grab option). But still ...

Comment: Could you clarify a bit? *"The geometry-information is no longer taken directly (as in 12.04), but the shading around the window is now added to the placement"* - as reported to what? Also: *"When opening that window, it is placed below the current window. Ideally, I would like it to stay on top. Or almost."* - What window are you referring to with "That window".

Comment: ".. as reported to what": as it has been in 12.04.  "that window" is the gs see above

Comment: A lot has changed in-between 12.04 and 14.04, so install CCSM (Compiz-Config Settings Manager) turn off the place window module and try again, or alternatively, turn it on and have CCSM place the window for you instead of emacs. If you have no clue what I'm talking about [ping me in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room).

Comment: @Fabby: Is there any doc to read?

Comment: the compiz.org website seems to be off-line right now, but [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/101006/how-to-tweak-unity-on-ubuntu-with-the-compizconfig-settings-manager/) is some nice documentation.  You need the "Place Windows" module ...

Comment: @false How were you calling it from emacs?

Comment: @Tim: very indirectly: Actually, there is another process started within Emacs, and that does call ghostscript directly.

Comment: @Tim: Same problem if I call ghostscript manually with `M-! ghostscript&`

Comment: So? Does the CCSM trick work?  (14 hours before the reward is lost...  If it did, I'm willing to post an answer...

Comment: @Tim: In the meantime it works with it - actually, I realize that other answers already contained what I sought for. However, there were several obstacles: Like warnings for installation and the like that were for me all red flashlights.